# GroupBy a list of key-value pairs then regroup the result

Tags: c#, linq, grouping

I want to group a list of key value pairs by key, then to group all the keys which have the same list of value.

Here is an exemple

```
| Key | Value |
|:----|------:|
| 1   | A     |
| 1   | B     |
| 1   | C     |
| 2   | A     |
| 2   | B     |
| 3   | A     |
```

Here is the result I would like to have

```
| Keys | Values |
|:-----|-------:|
| 1,2  | A,B    |
| 1    | C      |
| 3    | A      |
```

I started with a classic `GroupBy`, but I am stuck in the second step to group the keys

```
var pairs = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
{
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("1", "A"),
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("1", "B"),
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("1", "C"),
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("2", "A"),
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("2", "B"),
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("3", "A")
};
var groupingFirstStep = pairs.GroupBy(p => p.Key);

| Key  | Values |
|:-----|-------:|
| 1    | A,B,C  |
| 2    | A,B    |
| 3    | A      |
```

Other examples: on the left the input, on the right the expected result

```
| Key | Value |          | Keys | Values |
|:----|------:|          |:-----|-------:|
| 1   | A     |          | 1,2  | A,B    |
| 1   | B     |
| 2   | A     |
| 2   | B     |

| Key | Value |          | Keys | Values |
|:----|------:|          |:-----|-------:|
| 1   | A     |          | 1,2  | A,B    |
| 1   | B     |          | 1    | C      |
| 1   | C     |
| 2   | A     |
| 2   | B     |

| Key | Value |          | Keys | Values |
|:----|------:|          |:-----|-------:|
| 1   | A     |          | 1,2  | A,B    |
| 1   | B     |          | 1,3  | C      |
| 1   | C     |          | 3    | A      |
| 2   | A     |
| 2   | B     |          Other possibility
| 3   | A     |          | 1,3  | A,C    |
| 3   | C     |          | 1,2  | B      |
                         |   2  | A      |
```

Comment: Your grouping has not the _same_ list of values - they just have some _intersection_ of values - and `1,3 - A` would be possible as well  - same for  `1,2 - A`

Comment: Why 1 and 2 should be grouped together? 1 has A, B and C, while 2 has A and B.

Comment: @MichałTurczyn Probably because they both have A and B, but then why is there not a group showing than 1, 2 and 3 have A in common?

Comment: @MichałTurczyn, my goal is to minimize the number of lines whatever the grouping keys

Comment: @vc74, other results are possible, the idea is to reduce the result of the first grouping by grouping again keys which share the same values

Comment: @Nicolas, your last table has the same number of lines than the second one, so, why not stick with that one?

Comment: @Magnetron, you are right, this example is maybe not the best. The idea is to group the keys which share the same values.

Comment: @AleksAndreev I added more examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you need. I omitted `KeyValuePair` with C, because I assumed that you would like to know how to group keys when the value (in this case `A,B`) is the same:

```
var pairs = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
{
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("1", "A"),
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("1", "B"),
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("2", "A"),
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("2", "B"),
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("3", "A")
};
var grouping = pairs.GroupBy(p => p.Key)
  .GroupBy(g => string.Join(",", g.Select(kvp => kvp.Value)));
```

Comment: It doesn't give the second line `1 | C`

Comment: If you omit the C you simplify too much, reintegrate it and you will see it doesn't work.

Comment: After spending time looking for a solution, it appears yours is the best I saw: group a second time by the list of values. So it only groups the exact match of values, but it is better than nothing. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Linq_Enumerable_GroupBy__4_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0___1__System_Func___0___2__System_Func___1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___2____3__) of `.GroupBy` to project the values out of it.

Something like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var pairs = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
    {
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("1", "A"),
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("1", "B"),
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("1", "C"),
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("2", "A"),
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("2", "B"),
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("3", "A")
    };

    IEnumerable<string> groupings = pairs.GroupBy(x => x.Key, x => x.Value, (x, y) => $"{x}\t|\t{string.Join(",", y)}");

    foreach (string groupItem in groupings)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(groupItem);
    }
}
```

Outputting:

```
1       |       A,B,C
2       |       A,B
3       |       A
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In the results I want 1 and 2 to be grouped because they have both A and B.